# Combining rows in one df with the same name but different columns values (sum and mean)

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to combine rows in one Dataframe that have the same name but different values in other columns. Some of these values contain sums, other contain average values. My real Dataset contains 500 rows and 12 columns.

To simplify:

---

```
df
name column1 column2 column3 
a      53     43      0.73    
a      16     19      0.69 
b      89     99      0.12    
c      67     12      0.52
```

I want to combine rows with identical values in "name". Column1 and Column2 need to be summed up. For values in column3 I need to create an average.

This is how it should look after

```
df
name column1 column2 column3 
a      69     62      0.71    
b      89     99      0.12    
c      67     12      0.52
```

I got so far that I created this:

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(across(c(column1, column2, sum))
```

How can I add the average for values in column3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sum` is in the wrong place. The syntax for [`dplyr::across()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html) is:

> `across(.cols, .fns, ..., .names = NULL, .unpack = FALSE)`

Your `across(c(column1, column2, sum))` supplies everything to the `.cols` parameter and nothing to `.fns`. As you wish to apply the `sum` function, it should be `across(c(column1, column2), sum)`.

You can assign the `mean()` by group by creating a new column. This should work:

```r
df  |>
    group_by(name)  |>
    summarise(
        across(c(column1, column2), sum),
        column3 = mean(column3)
    )
# # A tibble: 3 × 4
#   name  column1 column2 column3
#   <chr>   <int>   <int>   <dbl>
# 1 a          69      62    0.71
# 2 b          89      99    0.12
# 3 c          67      12    0.52
```

Comment: Yes that works perfectly, thank you very much!!!